# iphone toolbar showing view

Tags: iphone, ios, toolbar

ok, i cant find the method called by UIViewController that presents a new view.

i have an app based on UINavigationController. Once i come to a view showing details of the object, i have 1 toolBar at the bottom so i can give some options to user.
When he press on barButtomItem, i want to show a new view but not changing the navigationbar, so if i press back button he goes back from detail view and not from new option.

i know method pushViewController but does not work as i want.

thx in advance!

edit: just to be a more bit more clear if i call 
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:loteCompraViewController animated:YES];
i get a new view, related to the new controller but it also changes the navigationbar and that is not good for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "pushViewController doesn't work"? What does it do? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: if i call [[self navigationController]pushViewController:loteCompraViewController animated:YES]; its show a new view but it changes also the navigationBar and thats is what i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

Give your view controller of the "view showing details of the object" two methods: `isShowingOverlayView` and `dismissOverlayView`.  In `isShowingOverlayView`, return YES if you're showing the "new view" because "he press on barButtomItem".  In `dismissOverlayView`, hide the "new view".

Then make your own subclass of UINavigationController.  In your subclass, override `popViewControllerAnimated:` to use those methods of your object-detail view controller, like this:

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self.topViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(isShowingOverlayView)]
        && [(id)self.topViewController isShowingOverlayView])
    {
        [(id)self.topViewController dismissOverlayView];
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [super popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Use this subclass instead of the standard UINavigationController.